# Mercurial - Get modified files in a branch but stop when the branch was last closed

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I want to get the committed files in a branch up until the branch was created.

For that I use:

```
hg log -b foo --no-merges --template="{files % '{file}\t'}"
```

But this gives too many changes when the branch existed before and was reopened (after being closed)

Example in the image below:

1. Open a branch 'test' and commit changes
2. Merge the branch to default
3. Close the branch and merge
4. Open another branch with the same name 'test'
5. Commit some changes

**The question is: How can I get the committed files only in step 5 and not include the files from step 1?**

[image]

Comment: Can you avoid reusing the branch name? That seems like it will be confusing and cause other problems also.

Comment: I can avoid it but I like to have all the work done for a feature on the same branch name. What problems can it cause?

Comment: I meant problems like what you're asking in this question.  Incidentally, you might also look into hg topics which are like lightweight branches. Doesn't solve your immediate issue but could be useful.

Comment: You can't.  Since you merge 1st test into default, default contains all of 1st test's changes.  2nd test branches from default, so still has all the changes.  If you don't want changes in 1st test, branch from "initial" default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't close branch, it's waste of time
2. Even if you prefer to continue closing branch - don't merge closed branch to mainline, it's waste of time (content of branch not changed on closing)
3. If you want to get files from some part of changesets for branch, you have to define and use revset for this subset of changesets in branch: if you'll follow pp.1+2 recommendation, revset will be something like (TBT!) `last(branch('test') & branchpoint()):heads(test)`

Comment: Closing branches and merging them is not a waste of time, especially in very large repos.